# Oracle changes encoding

Tags: oracle

```
select rawtohex(UNISTR('\0436')) from dual
```

returns 0436

```
update my_table set my_column = UNISTR('\0436') where id = 248149;
SELECT rawtohex(my_column) from my_table where id = 248149;
```

returns E6

so I put symbol in UTF8 and get it back in CP1251. Why so?

Comment: What is your database encoding? Can it actually store wide characters? NLS_CHARACTERSET. If not you might want to reinstall or use a NVARCHAR/NCLOB column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the `unicode` string into `varchar2` column. Consider saving them in the `nvarchar2` type columns.

```
create table my_table 
(
id number(10),
my_column varchar2(100),
my_column_uni nvarchar2(100) 
);

insert into my_table values(1,  UNISTR('\0436'), UNISTR('\0436'));
commit;

select rawtohex(my_column), rawtohex(my_column_uni)
  from my_table
 where id = 1;
```

The output will be `E6` for varchar2 column and `0436` for nvarchar2 column. Oracle changes the encoding based on your [nls parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG188), where you have `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`  NLS parameters. You can query your specific parameters by.

```
select *
from nls_database_parameters
```